# Build GDB in Mingw error, configure: error: no enhanced curses library found; disable TUI

Tags: gdb, mingw, tui

I tried to build GDB 7.51 in mingw for cross platform debugging, and I found GDB has TUI as frontend. Anyway, I configure GDB with --enable-tui, and then make always stop with error message:

**configure: error: no enhanced curses library found; disable TUI**

I checked this problem by google, and then I downloaded ncurses source from GNU

[ncurses 5.9](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/)

build and install it in my c:/mingw/msys/1.0/local/

run the configure of GDB with following script statements

```
export PATH=$PREFIX/gccbinutils/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw/bin
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/include:/usr/local/include/ncursest:/usr/include:/c/mingw/include
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/include:/usr/local/include/ncursest:/usr/include:/c/mingw/include
export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/c/mingw/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/c/mingw/lib
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/c/mingw/lib"
export LIBS="-lncursest"

$BUILD_MIPSGCCDIR/gdb/configure --prefix=$PREFIX/$pkg --target=$TARGET \
                --enable-tui \
                            --enable-curses \
                --enable-sim > $BUILDPATH/$TARGET$pkg.conf1.$argn.log  2>&1
```

but it did not work. Make stopped with following messages

```
checking for zlib.h... yes
checking for library containing dlgetmodinfo... no
checking for iconv... yes
checking for iconv declaration... install-shextern size_t iconv (iconv_t cd, char * *inbuf, size_t *inbytesleft, char * *outbuf, size_t *outbytesleft);
checking for library containing waddstr... no
configure: error: no enhanced curses library found; disable TUI
make[1]: *** [configure-gdb] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/d/tools/buildmipsgcc/build_gdb'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have searched the **waddstr** , and sure it was exist in my **c:/mingw/msys/1.0/local/lib/libncursest.a**.

Comment: _"It didn't work"_ supplies zero information on what exactly didn't work. Expand your question.

Comment: Thanks Haroogan, I have added the "make messages".

Comment: Do you have the corresponding `*.la` file in the same directory as `libncursest.a`?

Comment: @Haroogan      There is no libncursest.la be generated when I build ncurses. I built **ncurses** with following configuration :  CC="gcc -m32" LD="ld -m32" ./configure --prefix=$DEST_DIR/$pkg \
  --without-cxx-binding --without-ada --enable-warnings --enable-assertions --enable-reentrant --with-debug --with-normal --disable-home-terminfo --enable-sp-funcs --enable-term-driver --enable-interop --with-pthread > $BUILDPATH/$TARGET$pkg.conf.$argn.log  2>&1

Comment: Well you definitely need it because otherwise Autotools would be unable to locate it. Did you do `make install` for `ncurses`? If yes, then `*.la` should have been automatically deployed.

Comment: Yes, I have ran make install, but no *.la exists. only libformt.a libformt_g.a libmenut.a libmenutZ_g.a libncursest.a libncursest_g.a libpanelt.a libpanelt_g.a in **installed dir/lib**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, lets try to fool Autotools by providing hand-written `libncurses.la`:

```
# libncurses.la - a libtool library file
# Generated by ltmain.sh (GNU libtool) 2.2.7a
#
# Please DO NOT delete this file!
# It is necessary for linking the library.

# The name that we can dlopen(3).
dlname=''

# Names of this library.
library_names=''

# The name of the static archive.
old_library='libncursest.a'

# Linker flags that can not go in dependency_libs.
inherited_linker_flags=''

# Libraries that this one depends upon.
dependency_libs=''

# Names of additional weak libraries provided by this library
weak_library_names=''

# Version information for libncurses.
current=5
age=0
revision=9

# Is this an already installed library?
installed=yes

# Should we warn about portability when linking against -modules?
shouldnotlink=no

# Files to dlopen/dlpreopen
dlopen=''
dlpreopen=''

# Directory that this library needs to be installed in:
libdir='c:/mingw/msys/1.0/local/lib'
```

Check paths and names that I've supplied, if they are different - change them. Report if it still does not work, and I'll try to expand it further until we finally fix it.

Comment: It still get error.

libtool: link: `/usr/local/lib/libncursest.la' is not a valid libtool archive
make[4]: *** [libbfd.la] Error 1

Comment: Open `ltmain.sh` scripts in `ncurses` and in `gdb` and tell me versions of both. You can do so by locating a line like this `VERSION=1.5.24`.

Comment: GDB: VERSION=2.2.7a, but no ltmain.sh in ncurses

Comment: Just updated the `libncurses.la`. Try now. By the way, the reason why it was not generated on the installation stage of `ncurses` is that the distribution of it didn't supply `ltmain.sh`, but that's weird.

Comment: The make takes long time, but the problem seems to be solved. I updated the libcurses.la, and found the [pre-compiled ncurses package of mingw](http://waterlan.home.xs4all.nl/mingw/ncurses/). Install it to my /usr/local directory. Some files in this ncurses package has different name from my built ncurses. Anyway, thanks Haroogan.

Comment: No problem. Yes, the `ncurses` built by you looked very suspicious: no `*.la` and especially this weird suffix `t`. Good, that it finally works now.